# Routing table for multiple vlans on single nic

Tags: debian, networking, vmware, vlan

In my server I have two nics, eth0 that's a dedicated interface and eth1 that's has configured as trunk on my vmware. In eth1 I need to create multiple vlan's. I was able to do it but I can't redirect the traffics between each vlan. For example:

```
eth1.96
ip: 192.168.3.2/24
The gateway of this vlan is 192.168.3.1
```

When I do ping -I 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.1 return unreachable network, seems that I am missing a route.

Comment: It's not entirely clear which addresses are assigned to which vlan, but what you have said seems to imply that the vlans are sharing the same /24 subnet. You should use different subnets for the vlans.

Comment: My vlans
vlan96 192.168.3.0/24
vlan97 192.168.4.0/24
vlan98 192.168.5.0/24

Answer (score 1):

Besides setting up the NICs, VLANs and networks properly, for doing routing in your linux server you also need to add to your /etc/sysctl.conf the following lines:

The first for IP forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

The second for disabling anti-spoofing rules, to be able to use several networks in the same NIC:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

To activate those rules, do:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: I did this but stil the same.
This is my network config
[link](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2017/07_w27/1180202/ifconfig_vlan1.png)

Comment: Your network config looks ok to me (although the addresses are different than the ones in your question). Could you please elaborate a bit on your setup; what is the network topology, what is virtual (vmware) and what is physical, what you expect to work but doesn't and the exact error message?

Comment: @AndréBolinhas Network config seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

See the `ip route` command.

If you ran `ip route list` you would not see `192.168.3.0` in your routing table.

You can create a route using:

```
ip route add [IP]/[PREFIX] dev [INTERFACE] via [GATEWAY]
```

There are more options, check `man ip-route` if you need more flexibility.

---

So for your example you need:

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth1 via 192.168.3.1
```

Comment: The OP has used a Debian tag. /etc/sysconfig is RH specific.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Removed the `/etc/sysconfig` mention, didn't realize that was RH specific.

Comment: This is my network config
[link](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2017/07_w27/1180202/ifconfig_vlan1.png)